# I am creating table using multirow and multicolumn but in last two column, vertical line is missing, can't able to figure out why?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

    \begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Iterations}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{X}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{1}$}}
            & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{2}$}}
                & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{3}$}}
                    & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{4}$}}
                    &\multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{5}$}} \\
                    
    \cline{2-4}
    & \textbf{$x_{1}$}
        & \textbf{$x_{2}$}
            & \textbf{$x_{3}$}
            &   &  &                                 \\
    \hline
\makecell{0}
    & 0.45   & 0.10    & 0.10 & 5 &4 &6 &7 &1  \\
    \hline
\makecell{1}
     &  & &  &  & & & &      \\
    \hline
    \makecell{2}
    & 1&2&3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &5 \\
    \toprule
    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please give the complete code including the class of the document as well as the necessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Iterations}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{X}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{1}$}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{2}$}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{3}$}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{4}$}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{$f_{5}$}} \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & \textbf{$x_{1}$}
        & \textbf{$x_{2}$}
        & \textbf{$x_{3}$}
        &   &  &&&                                 \\%<----add
        \hline
        \makecell{0}
        & 0.45   & 0.10    & 0.10 & 5 &4 &6 &7 &1  \\
        \hline
        \makecell{1}
        &  & &  &  & & & &      \\
        \hline
        \makecell{2}
        & 1&2&3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &5 \\
        \toprule
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```